# Trading View Pine Script : How to Draw a Simple Line Using line.new function from market open to market close?

Tags: pine-script, trading, pine-script-v4, pine-script-v5

I want to draw a line using line.new function, that follows the below:

Time Axis :
**Automatically starts from Market Open and ends at Market Close.**
For all Markets, International and Local, and Across All Asset Classes. Not restricted to a specified time.

Price Axis:
Daily Pivot Point

Your Help is much appreciated.
Please

```
//@version=5
indicator('Pivot', overlay=true, shorttitle='Pivot', precision=1, max_bars_back=4500)

//******************LOGIC**************************
//cenral pivot range
pivot = (high + low + close) / 3  //Central Povit


//******************Line**************************
line.new(x1 = time('D', "open"), y1 = pivot ,         x2 = time('D', "close"), y2 = pivot ,               xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=line.style_solid, width  = 2, color  = color.new(#0000FF, 0)) //
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just extend the line to the right.
Also, your pivot calculation has a Pine built-in [hlc3](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_hlc3)

```
//@version=5
indicator('Pivot', overlay=true, shorttitle='Pivot')

// define line, extend to the right
var line    pivotLine = line.new(na, na, na, na, xloc=xloc.bar_time, style=line.style_solid, width=2, color=color.new(#0000FF, 0), extend=extend.right)

pivot = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', hlc3[1])

// new day?
if ta.change(dayofmonth)
    // move line
    line.set_xy1(pivotLine, time,   pivot)
    line.set_xy2(pivotLine, time+1, pivot)
```

Comment: This code needs tweaking, but is workable. I get the point. Much appreciated.